# Conditionally delete rows in data frames in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, character, conditional-statements

I have a data.frame that consists of 2 variables. Each variable is a list of character vectors. I.e. each observation corresponding to each variable is a character vector:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Var1 = list(c("A", "B"), c("C", "D", "E")), Var2 = list("F", 
"G")), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class ="data.frame")
```

I am trying to apply a function of this kind:

```
df$Var1 <- df$Var1[lengths(df$Var1)>2]
```

However, I get the expected error message explaining that this is not possible since the result would yield a data.frame with differing number of rows. I want this to delete that whole row instead. I.e. delete the corresponding observation (I want the corresponding Var2 observation to be dropped as well). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `df[lengths(df$Var1) > 2, ]`?

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks :)

Comment: However, this preserves row.names such that the only row that is left (in the example above) is called `row.names = c(2L)`. How can I fix this?